# How do I get a google user's name and put it in my GWT widget?

Tags: gwt

I am using GWT to create a widget that interacts with a remote server's REST API, and it will live on a Google site.

I would like to grab a user's name that they used to log on to Google Apps, and populate the name field with their name.

How might I go about doing this?

Thanks,
brl8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the guide to using Google accounts for user authentication:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/

You get limited information about authenticated users, including their email address and whatever name they chose for their Google account.

If you host your app on Google App Engine, there is a special User service that makes authentication with Google accounts very simple.

Comment: By the way, based on my extremely scientifically rigorous sample size of one question, I can confidently say that Stack Overflow has better answers than the Google Developer's Google Web Toolkit forum.